# Pandas how to turn each group into a dataframe using groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe looks like,

```
A    B
1    2
1    3
1    4
2    5
2    6
3    7
3    8
```

If I `df.groupby('A')`, how do I turn each group into sub-dataframes, so it will look like, for `A=1`

```
A    B
1    2
1    3
1    4
```

for `A=2`,

```
A    B
2    5
2    6
```

for `A=3`,

```
A    B
3    7
3    8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, need convert `groupby` object to `dictionary of DataFrame`s:

```
dfs = dict(tuple(df.groupby('A')))
print (dfs[1])
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4

print (dfs[2])
   A  B
3  2  5
4  2  6
```

Comment: why that and not via `get_group()`? Which is more performant? :)

Answer (score 2):

By using `get_group`

```
g=df.groupby('A')
g.get_group(1)
Out[367]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  3
2  1  4
```